# Java method overloading error with same return type?

Tags: java, overloading

while executing a basic method overloading program I am consistantly getting the following error:

> sh-4.3$ javac HelloWorld.java
>   HelloWorld.java:10: error: method show() is already defined in class HelloWorld
>           static void show()
>   HelloWorld.java:25: error: method show(int,int) is already defined in class HelloWorld
>            static void show(int a,int b)
>   2 errors

The code for the program is as follows

```
    public class HelloWorld{
       static int show()
         {
             int c = 5+10;
             System.out.println("hello");
             return c;
         }
        static void show()
         {
             int c = 5+10;
             System.out.println("void"+c);
         }
         static int show(int a,int b)
         {
             int c = a+b;
             System.out.println("hello");
             return c;
         }
         static void show(int a,int b)
         {
             int c = a+b;
             System.out.println("hello void args"+c);
         }
     public static void main(String []args){
    int a=5,b=5;
        int c=show();
        System.out.println("hello"+c);
        show();
        c= show(a,b);
        System.out.println("hello"+c);
        show(a,b);

     }
}
```

Comment: how will you know, wich show() Method to call? void or int?

Comment: Just rename one of your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A  very simple rule exists for the signature of the methods in java:

Method signature only includes the name of the method + input parameter(s).

So the return type of the method is not included in the method signature.

On the other hand overloading means:

Having two or more mathods in a class with the exact same name but different parameter types or different number of parameters or both.

Compiler does not indicate the return types of your methods, so can not understand the difference between two show methods with two int parameters. Same mistake happens for your two show methods without parameters.

Hope the clarification would be enlightening.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the entire clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot define 2 methods in java with same name and same parameter but with different return types.

In the [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) you can find the answer:

> The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating
>   methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature
>   even if they have a different return type.

Answer (score 1):

static void show(int a,int b)

static void show(int a,int b)

this is not support in java. because of the parameter list of two methods are same

There are two ways to overload the method in java

```
By changing number of arguments
By changing the data type
```

Answer (score 0):

Concept of overloading do not ditiguish two methods/function by return type. hence both the methos are considered to be having same signature.

To overload the method, two methods should have same name but diffrent parameter list. Parameter list could be different in number or datatype used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a misunderstanding of what method signature really means. To beef up that knowledge, please refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). especially this part is important:

> Definition: Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the
>   method signature—the method's name and the parameter types.